# Sitecore Content Delivery security hardening admin folder

Tags: azure, sitecore, azure-cloud-services

We are using azure webapps for sitecore infrastructure.

We need to apply security hardening on CD i.e. disable the sitecore client access. I had a look at security hardening guide which mentions about disabling annonymous access to sitecore/admin access.
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/security_hardening/deny_anonymous_users_access_to_a_folder

However this is not possible in Azure web-apps as we don't have access to IIS.

What's the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use request filters.  See https://sitecorecommerce.wordpress.com/2015/11/19/block-access-to-sitecore-folder-for-content-delivery-with-requestfilters/

Here's the relevant config from the post:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security xdt:Transform ="Replace" >
    <requestFiltering>
      <denyUrlSequences>
        <add sequence ="/sitecore/" />
        <add sequence ="/_Dev/" />
      </denyUrlSequences>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Additional references are available here: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering

Comment: going to use this solution. I assume there are no negative impacts.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure the security configurations in the **web.config** for your Sitecore CD server. E.g. Add this configuration under the root  element at the end of your web.config.

```
<location path="App_Config">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <add accessType="Deny" users="*" />
                </authorization>             
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```